# Debian bridged wifi connection doesn't start with system

Tags: linux, networking, bridge

I have t debian pc which is used as router. 
I'm using hostapd for creating wireless acess point, and i've bridged ethernet and wifi using brige-utils.
My **/etc/network/interfaces**

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

setup bridge
auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    bridge_ports wlan0 eth0
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
```

My issue is that after system restart wifi connection(that is wlan0) doesn't added to brige automatically, thought it is supposed to. But then i restart networking or add wlan0 manually, everything works fine. Why can it be?

**Upd.** 
After system start brctl show:

```
bridge name  bridge id           STP     enabled interfaces
br0          8000.0030488e31ac   no      eth0
```

Right after /etc/init.d/networking restart

```
bridge name  bridge id           STP     enabled interfaces
br0          8000.0030488e31ac   no      eth0, wlan0
```

Comment: just for the record, I do believe you need to set a default gateway if you are using bridging. In your specific case, I do believe you need to set up a DHCP server instead. If you already have a DHCP server elsewhere the configuration http://superuser.com/questions/694182/how-and-why-is-this-ubuntu-system-getting-an-ipv6-address would work (with one small tweak). I got pointed to this and I believe the selected answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A station vif cannot be added to a bridge as is (blame wifi's layer 2 for that). `hostapd` has to turn your (default) `wlan0` station vif into an AP vif before adding that to a bridge (which is done by the `bridge=` `hostapd` configuration file option).

Therefore, you need to arrange a way to set up your bridge (without including `wlan0`) before starting `hostapd`.

Comment: I'm not shure i've understood you.. Yes, hostapd converts wlan into ap, but it's interface name remains the same for networking, isn't it? After all, when i just restarting networking daemon few seconds after system boot, everything appears at their places, and brige is fully operational

Comment: @Quadrat137: Nobody cares about the interface name. What i say is that you can't add `ẁlan0` to a bridge before hostapd runs. Therefore, you need to make sure `hostapd` runs after `br0` is configured and you should stop mentioning `wlan0` in `bridge_ports` because it will fail anyway.

Comment: I thought that bridge creation will just fail, if wifi is not in AP mode, but it is created - that's confusing me

Comment: Bridge creation and adding ports are different commands. bridge creation will not fail, but wlan0 will not be part of it if it is not in AP mode (or another appropriate mode, like mesh or 4addr sta). To add to the confusion, hostapd may create br0 if it does not exist, but will not configure any IP, and it will destroy it when killed.